# How Does AJAX work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this call :

```
// some code;
myAjaxCall(
      function abcd() {};
);

// more code
```

Can the more code and abcd executing in the same thread or different thread. I know it is asynchronous.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `myAjaxCall` is an ajax wrapper, and the first argument is the complete callback, the answer is "more code" will run before abcd function. But I'd need to see myAjaxCall function to know what is really going on.

Remember, the complete callback happens when ajax retruns. "more code" executes in the normal execution path.

Comment: Why does it matter what is in `myAjaxCall`?

Comment: because I don't know how that first argument is used. If, inside `myAjaxCall` arruments[0] is called, it would happen first.

Answer (score 2):

The AJAX request is asynchronous, but the Javascript code is synchronous and single threaded.

The code following the AJAX call will complete before the `abcd` function can run. The event that occurs when the response arrives can't be handled until the code exits and returns control to the browser.