# jQuery.get() Variables Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with jQuery's Ajax but in my case I need to store the response in global variables:

```
var points = Array()
$.get("/data", {"id": 1}, function(data) {
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        points[data[i].someid] = data[i];
    }
alert(points[22].someid.toString()); // it works fine
});

alert(points[22].someid.toString()); // undefined
```

However when I try to access the variable points outside of the scope of $.get() I just get an undefined object. But I get the right object inside $.get().

What's the best way/standard to manage context and scope in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009206/what-is-ajax-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: I don't have time to write up a proper response, but basically the code in the callback for `$.get` may have not been executed yet (and therefore the variable is undefined) because it is asynchronous -- which means it may run at a later undetermined point in time while the script continues execution.

Comment: @Sanchez So should I use **success** and $.ajax() instead?

Comment: @ccarpenterg: No. That's just the nature of AJAX (the A stands for asynchronous) -- it doesn't matter which interface you use. Technically, you could use the `async: false` option to get synchronous behavior but I would advise against it because it could lock up the UI while it is waiting for the HTTP request to complete.

Comment: @ccarpenterg, `function(data)` is the success callback in for the `$.get()`.

Comment: You should call the function that parses the data in the callback you used to set the data.

Comment: @Sanchez @hyperslug So the variable is there but it's not there when I call it with **alert**.

Comment: Think of it this way: if the server responds in 1 minute, then it's too early to read the results in the second alert. It will take 1 minute before the results will be there, so, before that time, there will be nothing in the array. `$.get()` returns immediately.

Comment: Where you have `// it works fine` is where you need to use `points`, e.g. bind it to the DOM or whatever.

Comment: @hyperslug Ok, I understand. Is there any way to ensure the user won't be able to trigger another event until all the points are there?

Comment: @ccarpenterg, no, you'll have to prevent that manually (see my update).  Basically the user can keep doing stuff while waiting for the `$.get()` to complete, so try to restrict any actions that might interfere with `points`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scope is fine, but the `$.get()` runs asynchronously.  It starts the call then immediately executes the second alert.  When the `$.get()` completes, it executes the `function(data){}`.  Whatever you were going to use out of that, you need to do in there.  If you go to firebug console after all this is over, you should find that `alert(points[22].someid.toString())` has what you expect.

---

You can disable elements in your code to discourage further user action:

```
var points = Array();

// prevent further user action
$('#actionButton').attr('disabled', true);
// optionally show a loading.gif to let them know the browser is busy

$.get("/data", {"id": 1}, function(data) {
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
        points[data[i].someid] = data[i];
    }
    alert(points[22].someid.toString()); // it works fine

    // process points data

    // hide loading.gif
    // re-enable user action
    $('#actionButton').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```