# Sending js variables to a php file via html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a weird question and i don't know what to search to find the answer for it

Can I give an html button's onclick function args? `onclick="func('Wednesday')"`

```
function func(a) {
    if (a == "Wednesday") {
       var day = a;
    }
} else {
    var day = "not Wednesday";
}
```

Given that this is possible, is there a way to take this var and send it to another file, preferably a php file?

<sup>sorry if this is a repeat, im new</sup>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is AJAX and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009206/what-is-ajax-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: what do you wana do ? you wana create a common function through which you can create an onclick which returns a value ?

Comment: see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: you can send data to other file using this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Comment: you can send data to other file using this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269307/using-jquery-ajax-to-call-a-php-function

Answer (score 0):

If You are asking about what i have written you can do that by creating function:-

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: never recommend inline js / css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to maintain code

Answer (score 0):

Your two questions are not related as you are may be thinking.

The first question where you want to do something like this `onclick="func('Wednesday')"` is doable but perhaps not in the way you are imagining, I will do it in someway like this

**HTML**

```
<a id="my-button">Click Me</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function func(a, e) {
   if (a == "Wednesday") {
       var day = a;  
    } else {
       var day = "not Wednesday";
    }  
 }

var btn = document.getElementById("my-button")
btn.addEventListener("click", func.bind(null, "Wednesday"))
```

Read more about this way of binding callbacks here https://www.w3.org/wiki/The_principles_of_unobtrusive_JavaScript

Also I used `bind` function of `Function` to attach arguments with my callback which will be passed to my function whenever callback will be called

Now the questions about passing props from javascript to PHP. Well, think about the flow of server to client. Your PHP sends the javascript to browser as plain text to browser which gets interpreted at user machine, which means when your javascript begins to run PHP was no more in context hence you can't simply pass vars from JS to PHP since one of them runs on server and other on client.

To pass the props from client to server you will need to create AJAX request