# How to push values into array by AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

When I load my page I try to insert values from my database into JS array using AJAX, and after that to get a random value.

```js
var arrayen = [];
$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'getEnglishWords.php',
 success: function(words){
  words = JSON.parse(words);
  for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
   arrayen.push(words[i].en);
  }
 },error: (error) => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }
});

console.log(arrayen.length);
```

When I run the page, its insert the values into the array (I checked in chrome console), but - the `console.log` I have added in the bottom print 0. its look like the `console.log` run before the AJAX run and makes the problem.

**Edit:** I try to split the `arrayen[12]` into own array. its mean every charater to be in array row. so I do this:

```
console.log(arrayen);
var array = arrayen[12].split('');
```

results:
[image]

and I got error: `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success function in `ajax` is a function to be run when the request succeeds. Therefore if you want your log your success results then put the `console.log` within your success function like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'getEnglishWords.php',
success: function(words){
    words = JSON.parse(words);
    for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        arrayen.push(words[i].en);
    }
    console.log(arrayen.length);

},error: (error) => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
}
});
```

Comment: Its work fine, but I have a question. I edit my answer please see.

Comment: @Dasmond Have you made sure you have some data in your array before performing your split?

Comment: yes. before I do the split I make `console.log` to the array

Comment: @Dasmond Share that too if you can. Your result.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I bothered you. I found the problem, its was in another function. thanks for all!

Comment: @Dasmond kk. CHeers!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is because you are using `asynchronous function` which is `$.ajax()`. That is why your `console.log(arrayen.length)` statement is running first then you are getting the data.

To run your program add `console statement` inside `success callback`. It will make sure that the length is going to be printed once you get the data from the server.

[What is ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932690/why-is-ajax-called-asynchronous)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayen = [];
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getEnglishWords.php',
    success: function(words){
        words = JSON.parse(words);
        for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            arrayen.push(words[i].en);
        }
    findArrayLength(arrayen);
    },error: (error) => {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});

function findArrayLength(x) {
console.log(x.length);
}
```

AJAX is asynchronous and doesn't lock up the browser. If you fire an Ajax request, the user can still work while the request is waiting for a response. When the server returns the response, a callback runs to handle it.

You can make the XMLHttpRequest synchronous if you want, and if you do, the browser locks up while the request is outstanding (so most of the time this is inappropriate)

Answer (score 1):

use jquery library's each function.

```
$.each(words, function(index, value) {
    arrayen.push(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `console.log(arrayen.length);` inside done like below.

```
    var arrayen = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getEnglishWords.php',
        success: function(words){
            words = JSON.parse(words);
            for(var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                arrayen.push(words[i].en);
            }
        },error: (error) => {
             console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }).done(function(results) {
        console.log("done : " + arrayen.length);           
});
```