# Calling server side javascript from the browser through internet

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverside-javascript

can anybody help me to call a server side javascript method from the client HTML page (browser) and get back the object from the server and process through internet.
 as like google maps api.

ex as how we added:
we added code to include server side java script  from the html code.
script 
 type="text/javascript" 
src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"

and we get the map object by calling the method of google map api.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), settings);
```

Thanks.
Satish.

Comment: @Jivings you can make the link have more sense by using `[text](url)` markup.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I would, but I paste that link several times a day. It makes it even more tedious to format it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take a look at [how AJAX works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work).

You need to make an AJAX request to your server, which will respond with data to the browser.

Comment: thanks @jivings, i want to provide an API to the external world who can access my app and implement in there web page.  like how google is providing a URL to include in our html code then we can display a google map in our web page.