# How does ajax form submission work?

Tags: ajax, jquery, ajax-forms

I know how to use ajax for submitting a form and all. What I am concerned about is, what is actually happening in the background when a form is submitted via ajax.

> How are the values transferred?  Encrypted or not?  And what is the
>   need of specifying submission type, I mean get or post, if the URL is
>   not showing the form fields?

**Edit**: Found this on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp):

- GET requests can be cached
- GET requests remain in the browser history
- GET requests can be bookmarked
- GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data
- GET requests have length restrictions
- GET requests should be used only to retrieve data
- POST requests are never cached
- POST requests do not remain in the browser history
- POST requests cannot be bookmarked
- POST requests have no restrictions on data length

How do these apply to ajax form submission?

Comment: Why haven't you made any research?

Comment: The request is made just like a "normal" HTTP request. The difference between GET and POST is more than just whether the fields show in the URL or not.

Comment: Is http://Google.com down for you today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, when you Ajax-submit a form, it is doing exact same thing as what would happen when you as a user GET or POST submit a form - except that it is done in an asynchronous thread by the browser - i.e. called XMLHttpRequest.

If you submit form as a GET request, all of the form values are stitched together as parameter strings and appended to the URL (form's ACTION URL) - prefixed by a ?. This means anyone who can intercept that communication can read the submitted form data even if request is sent to a HTTPS URL. The POST method sends form data as a separate block (from the URL) and if URL is HTTPS then form data gets encrypted.

It looks like you are just starting out in the world of web development - welcome to the world of programming. I would recommend reading up on some good web development/programming books (I don't want to promote any particular book here). Amazon may help suggest few good ones under "Web Development" kind of search terms.

Also, I suggest that you read up a little on GET vs. POST by googling for it (I can only include one or two links - google will show you hundreds).

Comment: From the question, I do not assume that OP is new `to the world of programming`

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ - probably I shouldn't too! I was attempting to be polite in saying that he should read up a little on something as basic as GET vs. POST. If question was only limited to Ajax, I wouldn't have assumed the "new" part. Oh well...

Comment: @smallworld: `If you submit form as a GET request, all of the form values are stitched together as parameter strings and appended to the URL (form's ACTION URL) - prefixed by a ?. This means anyone who can intercept that communication can read the submitted form data even if request is sent to a HTTPS URL`. What happens when it is an ajax get request?

Comment: @Aparan as I mentioned in the first paragraph of my answer... "exact same thing". Your GET request Ajaxified or not makes no difference. Send it over HTTP GET vs. POST - only thing you need to worry about is the size of the data being sent (see other answers).

Comment: @smallworld: How can one read the submitted form data with ajax get request? I mean there is no visible URL there.

Comment: Ok, I think this is getting to a point of a classroom training. You may not be able to find the URL of submitted request in the browser, but that's not how hackers steal data. Irrespective of what you see in your browser URL, when data is sent across the internet it can be read - and this is not a platform where you can learn such details. Sorry, but I won't be able to help anymore on this question. Good luck.

Comment: @Aparan this is one final note for you and anyone who might be looking for some help... Stay away from w3schools (see w3fools.com for why) and research things a little so you can ask well-informed questions to the community. And... you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For the clear understanding & behind the scene things please refer the links given below.

http://www.jabet.com/

[How does AJAX work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work)

Actually ajax request is same as the normal requests at the server end.

1. GET or POST has their own use cases. for example: GET has a limit of data transfer depending on the browsers from 1KB to 10 KB. where POST has no such limits.
2. For a server both AJAX & normal request both are same. so it depends on server code which method you wish to support.
3. ajax requests are NOT encrypted.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: @Aparan Read up on regular form submission. It's exactly the same with Ajax.

Comment: Anand Shah, AJAX requests over HTTP are not encrypted - requests over HTTPS should be. Before referencing anything from w3schools, you may want to check out http://www.w3fools.com/ - and next time find a more credible source - w3schools have managed to game google - lets make sure we don't fall for it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want a very detailed answer so you can find it yourself:

- Google it and read thoroughly the pages (wikipedia for example)
- Read http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/
- Inspect the packets between your browser and the server