# Asynchronous JSP Tag

Tags: java, jsp, tags, jstl

Is there a JSP tag that allows that part of the page to process asynchronously?  If not is there a way to create one?

Something like the following:

```
<Util:Asynchronous>
    <%
        DataSource source = ...

    %>
</Util:Asynchronous>
... rest of page
```

I don't want to have to wait for the data source to finish before processing the rest of the page.

Thanks.

Comment: we do such kind of things with AJAX

Comment: I was hoping to not use AJAX.  I was hoping for an AsyncContext wrapped up nicely in a tag.

Comment: Review your concepts about Web Development. This isn't possible without ajax.

Comment: you can warp up AJAX nicely in a tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX. Also it is bad coding practice to put your data access commands in your JSP pages. Very susceptible to hacks, not to mention performance hits.

Answer (score -1):

The servlet container must wait that you are page is entirely rendered before sending it back to the client. Thus your requirement makes no sense for me.

If a part of the page takes too much time to process, you could use Ajax to load a portion of your page. There is already [pages at StackOverflow about Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work).

Comment: Yes, it must wait till all operations complete to send the page back but I have two parts of the page that both require complex queries in the database and are independent of each other and want to execute them concurrently.

Comment: In that case, I think the JSP is not the right place to handle this. That's a job for your controller.