# Can anyone explain me the execution process of functions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small doubt on Execution cycle of `function` in jquery. I'm trying to do some stuff with `js`, And in my `script` I have one `custom function` that calls `on click` of a button. What happens is, when I call the `function` it will make some `ajax` call and assigns the result to a variable. According to my knowledge after the execution of the `function` next `statement` should `execute`. But here what happens is after `function` call before completing the `function` execution next statements are executing.

Structure of my script is :

```
var variable=false;
function myfunction(e){
.....
.....
$.ajax({});
.....
console.log('inside : '+variable);
}
$('#button').click(function(){
....
....
myfunction(n);
console.log('called : '+variable);
....
$.ajax({});
....
....
});
```

Console output:

```
Ajax call from the function;
called : false
Ajax call from called function;
inside : true
```

Can anyone explain this stuff....

Comment: can you post a simple fiddle

Comment: please add you ajax code

Comment: See ajax is asynchronous, so it doesnot wait other process to get finished.

Comment: for calling the function after completing the ajax is the right way.you should write the function inside the success block of your ajax function.

Comment: [An answer by **Pascal Thivent**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1510156/1059101) This might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the power of js callbacks!

the js callbacks will do things after, and callbacks will run when get response! But js will not wait for the callbacks excution to continue, the following functions will run! `Async` is the beauty of js.

so in your js file, you make a ajax call for something. while ajax's running, the console will not wait until ajax complete!

if you want to excute the ajax function `sync`, you may make a `config` in the `params {async: false},` then the console will wait until the ajax func complete then excute!

Answer (score 2):

it will heppen indeed like this just beacause your custom function is an `Ajax Call` not a normal code.

**Ajax** stands for **Asynchronous Javascript and XML**

So, the request processing occur smultanelously that is what for ajax is used.

that is the reason, why even before compelting your function execution , the next statements are being executed. ( asynchronously)

Hope this helps..

**Note:** What ever the code you put in the Call back function of the ajax , they will be executed only after ajax call is completed

Comment: How can I make else part of the calling function to execute after the ajax completion.

Comment: @james ..sorry i was not able to understand what you are asking,.What do you mean by else part?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. my issue has solved from jingyinggong's answer. I just had to make `async:false`.

Comment: @James..If you do want to wait for console , then you need to put async:false..but this violates the need for ajax which means execution in parallel..

Comment: may be you're right. But as our need we can use it, for that reason only they have provided `async:false` option.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `.ajax`:

- Assigns an *event handler* to run a function when a response to an HTTP request is received
- Sends the HTTP request

The next line of code runs immediately for the same reason that a line of code immediately after `$('foo').click(...);` runs before the function you pass to click.

Comment: just curious when op is clicking the `button` why `console.log()` is not executed first?