# load table if user click on button

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have main page with table ,currently when I run my project and open the page the page is load with all the data which can take some time and I want to avoid it...

I've button of load in the page and I want that just when user click on this button load the table and not by default ,

how should I do that ?

How should I know if the user click on this button to load the data in the index page since when I run the project the index is called before the

view...

Comment: you might need [ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work) to load the data in json type when the button is clicked then construct the html..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the table to partial view and use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to load the table to main view when button is [clicked](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

**EXAMPLE**

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/controller/method/" /* This method should return a partial view that contains the table */
    })
    .done(function( html ) {
        $("#tabel").html(html);
    });
});
```

Thanks!