# Javascript, PHP and MySQL relations

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, iteration

I am currently working on a little project and I only just realised that the way I thought it would work, won't in fact work as JavaScript variables can't be sent to PHP that easily.

I have a Database full of members and each member has an id from 0 to x (lets just say `x = 10`) and I wanted to use a JavaScript for loop to iterate through and create everything easily.

Basically, the end product should be the following (except where it says `id = 0` it would be different for each entry)

```php
<tr>
    <td><?php echo mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM squad WHERE id = 0"))['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php switch(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT rank FROM squad WHERE id = 0"))['rank']){case 3:echo 'Lieutenant';break;case 2:echo 'Soldier';break;default:echo 'Private';} ?></td>
    <td><?php echo number_format(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT power FROM squad WHERE id = 0"))['power']); ?></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="gained0" value="<?php echo mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT power FROM squad WHERE id = 0"))['power']; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="rank0" value="<?php echo mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT rank FROM squad WHERE id = 0"))['rank'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

Obviously I can't type in a JavaScript variable into PHP so how would I be able to loop through and create the above for all entries?

Comment: you're completely mixing up client side and server side code. I suggest ditching javascript completely for a while, try to do everything in php, and come back to javascript once you have a better idea of how the server side works.

Answer (score 0):

My god that's an awful approach have a look in to AJAX http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29 how it is used ... You will need to implement some kind of API's with simple get requests.

With AJAX basically you can call URL-s from javascript and obtain the data that is returned from the page let that be text,html,json etc..

Here you can find a great explanation on how AJAX works [How does AJAX work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work) read through it you can find free tutorials on youtube also and after you got the idea rethink your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use javascript, I think you should use AJAX (google it). Best practice would be using only PHP and learning the difference between server side and client side.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it done with just PHP. The switch I had to think about but it works as far as I can tell.

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i<=10; $i++) {
        $r = "";
        switch(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT rank FROM squad WHERE id = $i"))["rank"]){case 3:$r="Lieutenant";break;case 2:$r="Soldier";break;default:$r="Private";}
        echo "<tr>" .
            "<td>" . mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name FROM squad WHERE id = $i"))["name"] . "</td>" .
            "<td>$r</td>" .
            "<td>" . number_format(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT power FROM squad WHERE id = $i"))["power"]) . "</td>" .
            "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"gained$i\" value=\"" . mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT power FROM squad WHERE id = $i"))["power"] . "\"></td>" .
            "<td><input type=\"number\" name=\"rank$i\" value=\"" . mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT rank FROM squad WHERE id = $i"))["rank"] . "\"></td>" .
        "</tr>";
    }
?>
```