# How to retrieve the value sent from struts action in javascript by parsing json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, gson, struts-1

I am newbie. I am sending the data from struts action using httpservlet response. What should i do to retrieve this value in javascript to set these values to an html element.

Used Struts action and httpservlet object to write to the response.

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); //using gson-2.3.1.jar 
//log.debug("Printing values ... ");
//log.debug(gson.toJson( languagesResponse.getLanguages()));

response.setContentType("application/json");
// Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object to the output stream      
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
// Assuming your json object is **jsonObject**, perform the following, it will return your json object  
out.print(gson.toJson( languagesResponse.getLanguages()));
out.flush();
```

Let the json return the value as :

[{"stringCode":"default","numberCode":0,"__hashCodeCalc":false},{"stringCode":"en_US","numberCode":1,"__hashCodeCalc":false}]

I want to get this value for javascript elemtent.

Answer (score 0):

How you respond from HTTP server isn't relevant to this question as what you are asking is client-side code for that. Also this can be seen as duplicate of multiple questions from which you can get the answer to this like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510156/1744702) (has nice overview of the idea). You can also check these two parts of jQuery for actual code examples: [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) & [DOM manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Comment: i know its client side code to handle, but i don't know how should i get the response data at client side..

Comment: Did you check the links I provided? Those should have quite extensive material about handling all you asked.