# StartBootstrap email server

Tags: php, email

I am currently using github to host my website and my code and I am also using a php template file from startbootstrap to create the form itself. I put my yahoo email on the template and test it on my browser but it says the server isn't responding. Does Yahoo support this or is there any way to make this work? 
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/

Here is the website where I got my template and you can find the PHP file under contact_me.php.

Answer (score 0):

*You 've may solved this, but I suppose this will help future searches.*
There are two main points to get this working for your purpose.

1. Conforming the mail address to a valid one of yours, by changing the following line on `/mail/contact_me.php`, to a valid email address of yours: `$to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com';`.

*This is the only required text/code configuration.*

2. By taking a glance at the responsible for the mailing functionality script (and especially, at the part that starts with `$.ajax`), you 'll notice that there is an [AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510156/2486904) to the previously mentioned file (`/mail/contact_me.php`).

But, by default, browsers don't allow AJAX requests (for security reasons) to files located on your local file system. So, this means two things: you have to either configure your browser in order to allow local files access or just **run your app in a web server**.

You want your site on the web, so going for the second one of the above statements (marked in bold), should work. If not, then it's probably a permissions or security problem with the web host. Some web hosts don't allow forms to send emails out to popular mail servers (like Gmail or Yahoo) so I would try using a private domain. If it still doesn't work, your best bet is to contact your web host to see if they can help you.

Comment: Good answer but you need to place your code changes into the answer itself. What if that GitHub URL changes? Future users won't be able to find what you were referring to