# Defered image loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

As you Know new images may be loaded after page load completed using event . for example i can fire a JQuery click event to run foo function that  adds an image to a Div, and then that image will be loaded without needing to use Ajax . so what's going on?
whats the difference between using Ajax  and just add that image to page using an event?

Comment: Are you asking what AJAX is? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work

Comment: Agreed with DavieBrown. i guess you misunderstood the ajax. there is no need of ajax to create any image in a webpage but javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> image will be loaded without needing to use Ajax . so what's going on?

This is your browser doing it's magic. The moment you add a url to an image source, your browser sends the request (to where ever the image is located ) and handles the response automatically.

> whats the difference between using Ajax and just add that image to
>   page using an event?

Well it's straight forward. Ajax is not meant to "get" images. You could eventually use AJAX to get an image url or a list of image url's and apply them to img element(s)... but the browser still automatically sends the request and handles the response.

Taken from the comments, you should read this to fully understand how AJAX works.

[How does AJAX work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work)

Comment: Nope. It also works for videos ( http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp ) and iframes ( http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp ) and script elements and link elements as well as others.