# When is AJAX not used in pair with REST?

Tags: ajax, rest

Since the use of AJAX can come into play when we want to GET something from the database, or POST something there

Is it usually used with REST or for some other cases? If so, what those other cases might be?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax can be used to call any address, it could be a PHP file, or something that returns a JSON.

Take a look at wordpress' use of Ajax
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Or their aproach through REST api
https://deliciousbrains.com/comparing-wordpress-rest-api-performance-admin-ajax-php/

Give this thread a look
[How does AJAX work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work)