# How to call a RESTful web service's function from an html page by javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-services, rest

I have a RESTful web service (java) , and I want to send a get request by a submit button to the web service.

The function in the web service that called "test" will **take a string** from a text input in the html page and **return a string** , then I need to take the string and put it in an paragraph tag without refresh the page

Here is my code :

The html page :

```
<input type="text" id="equation_input">

 <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="equation_submit" onclick="fun()">

<p id="value"></p>
```

The RESTful web service :

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.tarek.doctorMath.resources.test.*;

@Path("/first")
public class first_equation {

@GET
@Path("/{test}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String test(@PathParam("test") String equation) {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: what happens inside `fun()`? show us the code..

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called AJAX (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML)

there are tons of libraries to make ajax easy, but for something so simple, here is a simple pure JS example

```
//url: the url to call through ajax
//callback: a function to execute when it is done
//error: a function for if there was a problem with the request
function load(url, callback, error){
    var xhr;

    // here we check what version of AJAX the browser supports
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') 
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else {
        //internet explorer is stupid...
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0", 
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0", 
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",
                        "Microsoft.XmlHttp"]

         for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {
            try {
                xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);
                break;
            }
            catch(e){}
         } // end for
    }


    function ensureReadiness() {
        //not done yet
        if(xhr.readyState < 4) {
            return;
        }

        // all is well  
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            error(xhr);
        }      
    }
    //here we assign the function above to check if the AJAX call is finished
    xhr.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness;

    //send the request
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send('');
}

//we call the function like this:
load('http://example.com/page', 
  function(successText){
      //get the paragraph and assign the value
      var p = document.getElementById('value');
      p.innerHTML = successText;
  },
  function(error){
      console.log(error);
})
```

view this topic for more info on what AJAX is: [How does AJAX work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work)

Comment: where i write this code? in new class or anything else?