# How to execute JavaScript in PHP file executed from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I posted this earlier but it incorrectly got marked as a duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml), which isn't my problem. I'm not trying to run any JavaScript through using `innerHTML`, I'm trying to run JavaScript that is located in a PHP file called through Ajax/XmlHttp. I am using `innerHTML` in that JS, but I'm not writing more JS within that. So it's not a duplicate of that question and I'm trying it again now.

Not sure what's going on here. I'll explain the organization of my files first and then get into the code.

**The application-** Allows the user to select different attributes (i.e. year or name) and view pictures of matching results from a database.

**Files-** I have a `gallery.php` file that has a series of HTML form elements acting as selectors to get filtered results from a database. Whenever a selector is set or changed, the file sends a new request to a `get.php` file that uses Ajax to refresh the results without loading a new page. All that works great. My next task is to implement a modal section where I can click on an image and view a bigger version which I plan to do with JavaScript and CSS, but my intermediate goal is to just change some text at the bottom of the results from `get.php` again using JavaScript, just as a first step. But I can't seem to get any JavaScript written in `get.php` to fire.

**Code-**

This is `gallery.php`:

```html
<?php
 include_once("./../php/navbar.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
 <link href="/css/siteTheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
  .attributes span {
   margin-right: 1rem;
  }
 </style>
 <script>
 function changeParams() {
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
   document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
 };
  year = document.getElementById("years_select").value;
        nameFirst= document.getElementById("nameFirst_select").value;
        /* Ton of other getElementById statements here that I'm excluding to keep things shorter */

  url = "get.php?year="+year+......;
  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 } /* End function */
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
 <h1>Gallery</h1>
 
 <form>Details:
  <!-- -------------------- Year -------------------- -->
  <select onchange="changeParams()" name="years" id="years_select">
   <option value="All">Year</option>
 <?php
  include("/var/www/admin.php");
                $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $publicdbUsername, $publicdbPass, $dbName);
                if (!$conn) {
                    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
                }
                $sql = "select year from db group by year order by year desc";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<option value=" . $row['year'] . ">" . $row['year'] . "</option>";
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
  </select>
  <!-- A bunch of other selectors are created here following the same pattern as above of getting results from a DB -->

  <!-- -------------------- Searchbar -------------------- -->
  <input type="text" size="50" onkeyup="changeParams()" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search"></input>

 </form>
 <div id="test">Choose some filters to see some results!</div>

 </form>
</div> <!-- Ends content div -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is `get.php`:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 /* Bunch of CSS that's not relevant here */
  </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(".....");
  var parts = document.querySelectorAll("div.imgContainer");
  console.log("Found something:", parts);
  parts.addEventListener("click", function(){
      document.getElementById("anID").innerHTML = "Test...";
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 include("/var/www/admin.php");
 $year = $_GET['year'];
 //Bunch of other variables set here following the same logic, getting data from gallery.php

 $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $publicdbUsername, $publicdbPass, $dbName);
 if (!$conn) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
     echo '$conn';
 }

 $sql = 'select * db';
 
 /* ---------- Creating SQL statement ---------- */
 $clauses = 0;
 if ($year != "All") {
  if ($clauses == 0) {
   $sql = $sql . ' where year = "' . $year . '" and';
   $clauses = $clauses + 1;
  } else {
  $sql = $sql . ' year = "' . $year . '" and';
  }
 } /* Bunch of other if statements to get set information and add to sql statement as such */

 // Need to chop of the last ' and' from the sql statement
 $sql = substr($sql, 0, -4);
 $sql = $sql . ' order by year desc';

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if ($num_results == 0 or $clauses == 0) {
  echo "<p>No matches to your query. Try refining your search terms to get some results.</p>";
 } else {
  echo "<p>" . $num_results . " results matched your query.</p>";
  echo "<div class=results>";
  //echo "<div>";

  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    function modalFunction() {
    document.getElementById("anID").innerHTML = "test";
    }
    </script>';

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $pic = $row['pathToPic'];
  $wwwImg = substr($pic, 13);
   //echo "<span id=aCard><img src=" . $wwwImg . " height ='250px'>";
   //echo "<span class=text>" . $row['fullCardInfo'] . "</span></span>";
   echo "<div class=fullContainer><div class='imgContainer'><img class=image src=" . $wwwImg ."></div><p class=text>" . $row['fullInfo'] . "</p></div>";
  } // End while of results
  echo "</div>";// End results div//</div>";

  //echo '<div class="modal"><p id="anID"></p></div>';

 } // End else of "if results"
 mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<script>
 
</script>

<div>
 <p id="anID">This in a div</p>
</div>
<!--<span>
 <p id="anID">This in a span</p>
</span>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if that was messy, I chopped out a bunch of stuff that just gets/selects/filters some data. All that works and all variables that are left in there are set in my full code.

But the issue I'm having is writing JavaScript in `get.php` to change the text in the `<p id="anID">` tags. I've tried JS in a few different areas of `get.php`, from in the `<head>` tags, to echoing it in `<script>` tags in the PHP, to pure `<script>` tags after the PHP statements are done (I think I left them in a few different places).

Problem is that nothing I do works to change the text in the `<p>` tags I references. Additionally, the `console.log` statements in the header of `get.php` don't seem to get called either. They don't fire no matter where I place them in `get.php`. `Console.log` works fine in gallery.php so it's not some issue with my browser or anything.

Long term, I will be adding JS query selectors to bring up a bigger image when an image is clicked on, but for now I'm just trying to make ANY JavaScript work in `get.php` and I'm struggling to do so. I don't see how this is a duplicate of the suggested repeat as I'm not trying to run JavaScript through innerHTML here.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the different languages and [how AJAX works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work).

Comment: I fully admit I may not understand it fully, and see the answer I posted for something I realized, but to be honest this comment was not at all helpful

Comment: You may want to check out the [Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) guide on MDN as well.

Comment: I mean I've read Ajax guides and have a basic understanding of it. Can you tell me what I appear to be confused about? Because I'm not getting it from your links...

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that, it actually is trying to pass JavaScript through innerHTML as the information from `get.php` comes from this section of `gallery.php`:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        console.log("Response: ", this.responseText);
    }
```

So it appears this is a duplicate of the question I linked after all. Apologies. However, there are not great answers to that question, so any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

Is simply going to add the contents of `this.responseText` to the element `test`. I'm sure you understand that much, but what you want to do is completely wrong. The scripts within the output of `get.php` will NOT be executed at all and you have corrupted your HTML as well by including a second `<html><head>` and more.

A better approach would be if `get.php` returned the data from you DB query as a JSON string like so:

```
$data;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[]['pic'] = $row['pathToPic'];
    $data[]['wwwImg'] = substr($row['pathToPic'], 13);
}
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

And then back on `gallery.php` you do something like:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    formatResult(this.responseText);
}

// ... snip ...

function confirmJson(str) {
    var j = null;
    if (str) {
        try { j = JSON.parse(str); } 
        catch (e) { j = null; }
    }
    return j;
}
function formatResult(str) {
    var data = confirmJson(str);
    if (! data) {
        console.log("result is not JSON");
        return;
    }
    // do stuff with the data
    var i, max = data.length;
    var h = document.createElement("div");
    var img;
    for(i=0;i<max;i++) {
        img = document.createElement("src");
        img.src = data[i].wwwImg;
        img.addEventListener("click",function(){ alert("pic:["+ data[i].pic +"]"); },true);
        h.appendChild(img);
    }
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = h;
}
```